# Access violation in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

In a delphi Application, When I move mouse to a component that has Hint I see this error :
" Access violation at address 00484F3B in module 'Plibrary.exe'. Read of address 0000026C"
Why this happen?

Call Stack:

```
:758e9617 KERNELBASE.RaiseException + 0x54 
:458bf456 System.@UStrCmp 
:00407558 @UStrCmp + $2C 
Forms.TApplication.SetHint(???) 
Forms.TApplication.Idle(???) 
Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage 
Forms.TApplication.Run Plibrary.Plibrary 
:75ca1194 kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 
:7752b3f5 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 
:7752b3c8 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36"
```

And failing code is in System.pas file at line 17732 : "MOV ESI,[ESP]"

Edit (from comment):

In the remain.pas file at this procedure :

```
procedure TMainForm.ShowHint(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  if Length(Application.Hint) > 0 then begin 
    StatusBar.SimplePanel := True; 
    StatusBar.SimpleText := Application.Hint; //this line gives error 
  end else    
    StatusBar.SimplePanel := False; 
end;
```

Comment: You need to include a stack trace at the very least. It's probably a null reference somewhere in your mouseover event or something.

Comment: that means that something went wrong. You have an application..written in which Delphi version? you have the component with hint...which component? is that component created at run-time? we can not guess why this error occurs, if you don't give more explanations

Comment: I Use " RAD Studio 2009  Version 12.0.3170.16989", My Component is "BitBtn" ,this component is on a child form and the form is created at run-time.

Comment: You could show the runtime form creation. That could well be messed up.

Answer (score 6):

> Read of address 0000026C

This very low address is indicative of an offset to a member field of a `nil` object reference. Run under the debugger and make sure the debugger is set to break on exceptions. When it does, you should be able to work out which object reference is `nil`.

Quite possibly the AV happens in VCL code although it will almost certainly be due to an error in your code. If the debugger doesn't break at a very helpful location, enable Debug DCUs in the project options in order to see the VCL source code at the point where the exception is raised.

The stack trace you provide suggests that the error is in `TApplication.SetHint`, whilst performing a string comparison. The first line of `TApplication.SetHint` reads:

```
if FHint <> Value then
```

<strike>I bet the offset to the `FHint` of `TApplication` is `$026C` and that, somehow, your `Application` variable is set to `nil`. That said, I don't understand why the error would not have been raised earlier at `Length(Application.Hint)`. It's quite hard to debug this remotely!</strike>

Having looked at the layout of `TApplication`, I think we can rule out `Application` being `nil`. Perhaps `FHint` itself has somehow been corrupted, or perhaps even `Value`. I think it's going to take access to the actual code and a debugging environment to track this down.

Comment: I Use " RAD Studio 2009  Version 12.0.3170.16989", My Component is "BitBtn" ,this component is on a child form and the form is created at run-time.

Comment: Give us the details of the exception with a stack trace and we'll tell you what code we need to help you solve your problem. Tellingus what development environment you use is of no use.

Comment: When I enable Debug DCUs in the project options I see this error:
"Exception class EIntOverflow with message 'Integer overflow'. Process Plibrary.exe (3164)"

Comment: Are you running under the debugger? If so, do so. When you do so the debugger should break at the failing code.

Comment: the call stack (stack trac window) is at View->Debug Windows->Call Stack, or Ctrl+Alt+S

Comment: this is my call stack : ":758e9617 KERNELBASE.RaiseException + 0x54
:458bf456 
System.@UStrCmp
:00407558 @UStrCmp + $2C
Forms.TApplication.SetHint(???)
Forms.TApplication.Idle(???)
Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage
Forms.TApplication.Run
Plibrary.Plibrary
:75ca1194 kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12
:7752b3f5 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63
:7752b3c8 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36" And failing code is in System.pas file at line 17732 : "MOV     ESI,[ESP]"

Comment: That doesn't help much. Can you step through VCL code? Can you show the runtime form creation code? Can you stop adding detail in comments and instead add it to the question by means of an edit. That way it is readable and accessible.

Comment: In the remain.pas file at this procedure : procedure TMainForm.ShowHint(Sender: TObject); begin if Length(Application.Hint) > 0 then begin StatusBar.SimplePanel := True; StatusBar.SimpleText := Application.Hint;//this line gives error end else StatusBar.SimplePanel := False; end;

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided in the stacktrace:

**TApplication.Idle:**

```
Control := DoMouseIdle;
if FShowHint and (FMouseControl = nil) then
  CancelHint;
Application.Hint := GetLongHint(GetHint(Control)); // SetHint is called next:
```

**TApplication.SetHint:**

```
if FHint <> Value then // This is the UStrCmp which fails with a Int overflow
```

String + IntOverflow -> non terminating string. So the most probable cause is a string without a terminator.

**So where does the string come from...**

- GetHint(Control) searches the control (which is at the places you clicked with the cursor) and its parent for a hint that is not empty.
- GetLongHint searches the string for a | and if found, uses the part following the | else it uses the complete string.
- UStrCmp, is a long pieces of assembler code, that calls other pieces of assembler code. Some of them can raise the EIntegerOverflow error.

**Advise**

Use the debugger (with debug dcu's on) to see which string has no terminator (0 character at the end). And if you find it, try to solve it or expand the question if you want some more help from us.

Comment: Surely `UStrCmp` uses string length rather than zero terminators?

Comment: Yes, `UStrCmp()` does rely on the strings' embedded length fields and not on null terminators.  So it is more likely that either `FHint` or `Value` does not point to a valid `String` variable to begin with (I am guessing `FHint`, which would suggest the `Application` object pointer is nil).